# How to parse a JSON starting with a nameless array?

Tags: json, swift

I'm very new to parsing (and coding)

This is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "BTC",
    "currency": "BTC",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "logo_url": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/btc.svg",
    "rank": "1",
    "price": "8890.83451549",
    "price_date": "2020-05-05T00:00:00Z",
    "price_timestamp": "2020-05-05T17:07:00Z",
    "market_cap": "163265390419"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get a hold on the property `price` with the following:

```
struct GetPriceArray: Codable {
    let getPriceArray: [GetPrice]
}

struct GetPrice: Codable {
    let price: String
}
```

The problem is that the JSON path is `0.price` (as indicated by JSON Viewer Awesome) and with the above, it is not possible to get a hold of that `0`.

I already tried jumping directly to `.price` but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete

```
struct GetPriceArray: Codable {
    let getPriceArray: [GetPrice]
}
```

and decode an array

```
let result = JSONDecoder().decode([GetPrice].self, from: ...
```

Get the price with

```
result.first?.price
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ***GetPriceArray*** working with decoder and non-key JSON.

```
struct GetPriceArray: Codable {
    let list: [GetPrice]
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        var elements: [GetPrice] = []
        elements.reserveCapacity(container.count ?? 0)
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            if let element = try? container.decode(GetPrice.self) {
                elements.append(element)
            }
        }
        self.list = elements
    }
}
```

Test.

```
guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8),
    let getPriceArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode(GetPriceArray.self, from: jsonData) else {
        return
}
for i in getPriceArray.list {
    print(i.price)
}
```

Comment: Definitely too advanced (for now). However, many thanks for taking the time!